# Terminology for a graph that can be drawn in several planes?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

A graph is called planar if you can draw it in the plane without any edges crossing.  In circuit layouts, it's common to try to lay out a graph across multiple different planes, where edges can jump from one plane to another but can never cross one another in the same plane.

Is there a term for graphs that can be drawn in this way across $k$ planes?  Would it be something like a "multiplanar graph?"

Thanks!